# Border-radius generates eclipse, need 90degree rounded corners. CSS

Tags: html, eclipse, css, rectangles

So I'm trying to get a 90degree angle corner on my rectangle (width 96.6%, height 6.5%)

Applied settings on rectangle: Border-radius-bottom-left: 5%;
Border-radius-bottom-right: 5%;), this gives it a eclipse shape, but it needs to be a 90 degree corner.

What settings do I need to use to get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **absolute metrics** for your [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) e.g. `px`, `em` or `in` and not `%` to make sure, that `x` and `y` values are qual. Otherwise they will depend on the values of `width` and `height` and as long as your element isn't a square, you will get an ellipsis.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.rectangle {
  width: 96.6%;
  height: 6.5%;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle"></div>
```

Read [this nice article on CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/) about `border-radius`.

Comment: This did the trick, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help!

Comment: I wanted to upvote your answer and found it incomplete as it initially didn't explain *why*. Please explain the principle so I can delete mine. Thank you. I don't mind if you use my wording. I just wrote it to explain what's going on. Or use your own words, or quote some official stuff, it's all up to you :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, updated my answer.

Comment: Quite welcome. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You must first use border-radius in css and use it in a hard 
number whether it be in px, em, or the like.

If you find you have the same issue afterwards, the issue could also be that you are making the border radius too high for the level of padding inside the object. If you want to keep the object this size I would recommend you lower your radius to 5px. Otherwise increase the padding inside the object.